# Getting all resources with a name starting with 001XXX.jpg

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, filepath

I'm developing an iPhone and iPad application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I want to retrieve the path for all resources which name start with **001**. Their name is 001XXX.jpg (**XXX** is unknown). I don't know how many resources are.

For example, I will have bundle in app the following files:

001001.jpg
001002.jpg
001003.jpg

I want to get a NSArray with the path for each of this three files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you do it in two steps:

- Use the [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIGABFF) method to retrieve all the png files.
- Use the [NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB) method to filter out the pattern you want.

The code (not tested) could look like:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"."];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] '001'"];
NSArray *images = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code will be helpful to you.

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentDirectory];
for (NSString *tString in dirContents) 
{
    if ([tString hasPrefix:@"001"] && [tString hasSuffix:@".jpg"])
    {

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

Here the **documentDirectory** stands for the path  of  document directory.
If your files are situated at place other than document directory , obviously you may place the path there.